# IE7 CSS issue - why is there white space between my h2 and h4 tags?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have an unusual CSS issue in IE7.   Here's my html and css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
.generic_panel {background-color:red; padding:15px; display:block; overflow:hidden;}
.generic_panel h4 {background-color:green; margin:0px; display:block; float:left;}  
.generic_panel h2 {background-color:blue; margin:0px; display:block; clear:both; float:none;}
</style>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <section id="content">
<section id="payment" class="generic_panel">

        <h4><a href="http://mysite.com">Invoice # 000095</a></h4>
    <h2>Remaining Invoice Amount: $17.5<br/>
        <span>Original Amount: $17.50</span>
    </h2>
</section>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

When viewed in IE7, there is white space between the h4 and h2 tags. I've been trying to get rid of that white space.  I don't understand why the `.generic_panel h2 {margin:0px;}` and `.generic_panel h4 {margin:0px;}`  properties aren't getting rid of that white space.

What's even weirder is if I delete ANY of `padding:15px` or `display:block` or `overflow:hidden` from

```
.generic_panel {background-color:red; padding:15px; display:block; overflow:hidden;}
```

then it gets rid of the white space between h4 and h2.  Why would css properties in my `.generic_panel` influence the spacing between my h4 and h2 tags?

Please help me understand what the $@#%#$%$ is going on....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix it by adding `zoom: 1` to `.generic_panel h2`.

- Your original code with the problem in IE7: http://jsbin.com/evaxi3
- The same code with the fix applied: http://jsbin.com/evaxi3/2

This problem is due to not having [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) - adding `zoom: 1` provides the element with "layout", and fixes it.

Comment: Well, because it fixes a known behaviour of IE(7). Did you read through the hasLayout link my answer? Linked from inside that document is this: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/acidicfloat.html - notice the "differences" between the compliant FF, and IE. In your case, IE7 just does not behave according to the CSS spec until you apply "layout" to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note, browsers specify their own margin and padding values that are considered the default unless you override them with a CSS reset.

Example of a css reset:

```
* html
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

h2, h4
{
    margin:20px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

If you do this, you'll have to specify the padding and margin on every element as the * html resets all the values to 0 (or whatever you set them to).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what's going on, it's a pretty strange bug. I have seemed to be able to fix it for you though.

Working for IE7/8/9, Opera, Firefox

```
.generic_panel {background-color:red; padding:15px; display:block;  overflow:hidden;}
.generic_panel h4 {background-color:green; margin:0px; float:left;  width:auto;}  
.generic_panel h2 {background-color:blue; margin:0px; clear:both;  float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that float doesn't work quite right in IE7.

This works and looks the same in IE9,8,7 and FF4.  I don't have any others to test.

```
    .generic_panel
    {
        background-color: silver;
        padding: 15px;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .generic_panel h4
    {
        background-color:white;
        margin: 0px;
        display:block;
        float: left;
        clear:right;
    }
    .generic_panel h2
    {
        background-color:Gray;
        margin: 0px;
        display: inline-block;
        width:100%;
        clear:both;
    }
```

I also changed your colors to save my eyes... ;)